# oracle select count query not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am new to oracle db connection. I want to fetch count using select query. But select query is not working. Here is my code that I have tried:

```
string query = "SELECT count(username) FROM REGISTRATION where password = :password and mobile_no = :mobile_no";

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("mobile_no", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = username;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("email_id", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = username;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("password", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = password;
    
OpenConnection();
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int count = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
return count;
```

It gives the following error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number on executing line object obj =
> cmd.ExecuteScalar();

How can I resolve please?

Comment: There are two bind variables in sql but you're adding 3 parameters?

Comment: If I remove the extra parameter, same error is coming.

Comment: Maybe because you are adding the mobile_no as `varchar` instead of  `integer` ?

Comment: If the error is now going away what's the use of adding parameter `email_id`?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("mobile_no", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = username;` --> why assigning `username` to `mobile_no` parameter?

Comment: What happens if you run this query directly against the database?

Comment: It works and shows the count.

Comment: I removed the extra email_id parameter and now it is working fine. Thank you everyone for the help.